# Delegated types - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I am still trying to find a good solution to the Delegated Type feature and as I didn't find any good more detailed guide, I would like to ask here.

What I am interested in is what DDH said:

`Delegated types. With this approach, the “superclass” is a concrete class that is represented by its own table, where all the superclass attributes that are shared amongst all the “subclasses” are stored. And then each of the subclasses have their own individual tables for additional attributes that are particular to their implementation.`

In their example, I saw that they use the creator on superclass and is a shared attribute for the subclasses, and they are using that in the comments controller like:

```rb
Entry.create! entryable: Comment.new(content: "Hello!"), creator: Current.user
```

In this case, the `creator` will be always the same, so correctly is implemented like that.

**My question**:

(As they mention) what if you want the superclass to keep the title attribute (just an example), which all the other subclasses can use, how can I handle that? In this case, the title is mutable (value will be different on each subclass based on user input), how it should be implemented on the subclass controller.

random example:

Note: ofc I created the Productable module and included in the subclass models

```rb
# schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_08_23_191445) do

  create_table "laptops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "usb_ports"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "mobiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "front_camera"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "Product", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "productable_type"
    t.integer "productable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

```rb
# laptops_controller.rb

class LaptopsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @laptop = Laptop.new
  end

  def create
    @laptop = Product.create! productable: Laptop.new(laptop_params) # Here to add what for the title?
    redirect_to @laptop
  end

  private

  def set_laptop
    @laptop = Laptop.find(params[:id])
  end

  def laptop_params
    params.require(:laptop).permit(:usb_ports)
  end
end
```

```rb
# _form.html.erb

<%= form_with(model: @laptop) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :usb_ports %>
    <%= form.number_field :usb_ports %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Should I use nested attributes as with polymorphic associations? Does anyone have any suggestions? Or maybe, to add the title attribute on each subclass and the attributes, and on superclass to add only the attributes that never change? But then, what's the point?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone else faces the same issue, the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` option wasn't available for `delegated_type` when I was looking for that, hence I couldn't use nested forms for associated objects configured via `delegated_type`.

BUT:
**Rails 7** adds `accepts_nested_attributes_for` support to `delegated_type`
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41717

Comment: Banging my head how to exactly uses nested_attributes with delegated types, especially when it comes to the controller and form. Would you mind sharing your solution using accepts_nested_attributes_for please?

Answer (score 1):

> and on superclass to add only the attributes that never change

I think you are misreading the docs. I didn't know about this feature until today (so thank you for drawing my attention to it), but from what I can see, the goal of using a superclass like this is not to save space by reusing/sharing fields that are the same for all records (if they are truly the same for all records, they don't need to be fields. Just hardcode them or put into a config file).

So if you're creating Comments or Messages, each new comment or message will create its own Entry (the delegated superclass in this example). An Entry won't be shared and is therefore free to have mutable fields.

And yes, since this feature seems to be just a layer of sugar over polymorphic associations, you can/should use all the same methods (nested attributes, etc.)

Comment: Hey @Sergio, thank you for taking the time to answer! Maybe you are right and I misread the docs or maybe I didn't write my question correctly.

By never change, I mean in the example above that the creator will always be the current user - no frontend action needed (by user side), so correct is on the Entry.

So, let's make my question more clear and simple I guess

Comment: So @Sergio, let's use their example because you already mention that. Let's say we have one more but common attribute for both comments and posts, a boolean field called 'draft'. We want the user to decide if it's true or false when they create a comment or a post. Where you would add it? On superclass or at both subclasses? that my question basically but overdid it I guess on my post haha

Comment: @Steve: if both Comments and Messages can be drafts (as well as all potential future types of Entry), I'd put this field on the superclass (table entries)

Comment: Thank you @Sergio!! Your answer has already solved more than half of my question :)

The other thing from my original post, is how would you implement this? DO you have any suggestions maybe?

**  a case is my example about the title, which is on the products table and can be used on both subclasses. So how I could implement the create action? by adding nested attributes for the product?

Comment: @Steve: I _think_ it's the other way, mobile accepts_nested_attributes_for product.

Comment: yeah this is what I also meant with 'by adding nested attributes for the product'. Then as you correctly said, this is like syntactic sugar of polymorphic associations, everything else should work the same. Thanks!! I will give it a try :)